# Python 3 - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/mnist.pkl'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mnist

I'm trying to load the mnist data set for this neural networks and deep learning example (http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) but I keep getting this error.

```
>>> import mnist_loader
>>> training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()
  File "C:/Users/Joseph Gannon/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32\mnist_loader.py", line 68, in load_data_wrapper
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
  File "C:/Users/Joseph Gannon/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32\mnist_loader.py", line 42, in load_data
    f = open('mnist.pkl', 'rb')
  File "C:\Users\Joseph Gannon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\gzip.py", line 53, in open
    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph Gannon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\gzip.py", line 163, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/mnist.pkl'
```

This is the code I am using:

```
"""
mnist_loader
~~~~~~~~~~~~

A library to load the MNIST image data.  For details of the data
structures that are returned, see the doc strings for ``load_data``
and ``load_data_wrapper``.  In practice, ``load_data_wrapper`` is the
function usually called by our neural network code.
"""

#### Libraries
# Standard library
import _pickle as cPickle
import gzip

# Third-party libraries
import numpy as np

def load_data():
    """Return the MNIST data as a tuple containing the training data,
    the validation data, and the test data.

    The ``training_data`` is returned as a tuple with two entries.
    The first entry contains the actual training images.  This is a
    numpy ndarray with 50,000 entries.  Each entry is, in turn, a
    numpy ndarray with 784 values, representing the 28 * 28 = 784
    pixels in a single MNIST image.

    The second entry in the ``training_data`` tuple is a numpy ndarray
    containing 50,000 entries.  Those entries are just the digit
    values (0...9) for the corresponding images contained in the first
    entry of the tuple.

    The ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are similar, except
    each contains only 10,000 images.

    This is a nice data format, but for use in neural networks it's
    helpful to modify the format of the ``training_data`` a little.
    That's done in the wrapper function ``load_data_wrapper()``, see
    below.
    """
    f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    """Return a tuple containing ``(training_data, validation_data,
    test_data)``. Based on ``load_data``, but the format is more
    convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.

    In particular, ``training_data`` is a list containing 50,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  ``x`` is a 784-dimensional numpy.ndarray
    containing the input image.  ``y`` is a 10-dimensional
    numpy.ndarray representing the unit vector corresponding to the
    correct digit for ``x``.

    ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are lists containing 10,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  In each case, ``x`` is a 784-dimensional
    numpy.ndarry containing the input image, and ``y`` is the
    corresponding classification, i.e., the digit values (integers)
    corresponding to ``x``.

    Obviously, this means we're using slightly different formats for
    the training data and the validation / test data.  These formats
    turn out to be the most convenient for use in our neural network
    code."""
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def vectorized_result(j):
    """Return a 10-dimensional unit vector with a 1.0 in the jth
    position and zeroes elsewhere.  This is used to convert a digit
    (0...9) into a corresponding desired output from the neural
    network."""
    e = np.zeros((10, 1))
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is a file named `mnist.pkl` there? If yes, place it in the directory from where it'll be accessed. Eg: It seems like your program will access it from `../data/` directory, so place it there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately the formatting of your question is so messy that it is impossible (to me, at least) to figure out what's going on. Usually I'm happy to fix formatting issues myself but in this case, I won't even try because I can't hope to figure out which parts are meant to be code, which are meant to be text or whatever. Please try and fix this, otherwise I think the question is likely to get closed.

Answer (score 0):

After so many problems facing,

example

**Allowed**

temp="W:\Projects"

temp="W:\Python project"

temp="C:\users"

temp="C:\Program Files"

**Not Allowed**

temp="C:\Program Files (x86)"

temp="C:\Program Files (x86)\DocClass"

pickle.dump(train_tfidf_transformer,open(temp+"\train_TfidfTransformer.pkl","wb"))

my conclusion is two space not in folder name but if you give this path directly then it's work because when you pass a string like temp that time they check that string is raw string or not? if not convert in raw string if yes then no conversion

Answer (score -1):

I am like 99% sure you are giving wrong path to file to get error like this.

Answer (score -1):

.pkl file is created after running .py file. You must have mnist.py file in the specified directory. run 'python mnist.py'